# OpenSSH upgrade breaks scp

Tags: ssh

I recently upgraded one servers (running RHEL AS 5) from OpenSSH 4 server to OpenSSH 5.2 server.

Since the upgrade a customer is unable to scp files from the machine anymore. They use an ssh client from http://ssh.com/. 
I can scp files from and to the machine using openssh without problems.

We use "Public key authentication" and they are still able to ssh to the machine but not scp files.

Is there any known -obvious- cause for such incompatibilities? If not how can I dig deeper into this issue?

Here is a log from the client side:

```
user@srv/home/user> /usr/local/bin/scp -v cdr@xxx.xxx.xxx.51:/home/cdr/test .
scp:SshAppCommon/sshappcommon.c:133: Allocating global SshRegex context.
scp:Scp2/scp2.c:499: Received error "SSH_FC_OK"., msg: Globbing successful.
scp:Scp2/scp2.c:564: Starting transfer...
scp:/home/cdr/test
scp:SshFCTransfer/sshfc_transfer.c:3018: File list has 2 files.
scp:SshFCTransfer/sshfc_transfer.c:2567: Not yet connected, or connection down, waiting...
scp:SshFileCopy/sshfilecopy.c:940: Connecting to remote host. (host = xxx.xxx.xxx.51, user = cdr, port = NULL)
scp:Scp2/scp2.c:1679: argv[0] = /usr/local/bin/ssh2
scp:Scp2/scp2.c:1679: argv[1] = -l
scp:Scp2/scp2.c:1679: argv[2] = cdr
scp:Scp2/scp2.c:1679: argv[3] = -v
scp:Scp2/scp2.c:1679: argv[4] = -x
scp:Scp2/scp2.c:1679: argv[5] = -a
scp:Scp2/scp2.c:1679: argv[6] = -o
scp:Scp2/scp2.c:1679: argv[7] = clearallforwardings yes
scp:Scp2/scp2.c:1679: argv[8] = -o
scp:Scp2/scp2.c:1679: argv[9] = passwordprompt %U@%H's password: 
scp:Scp2/scp2.c:1679: argv[10] = -o
scp:Scp2/scp2.c:1679: argv[11] = nodelay yes
scp:Scp2/scp2.c:1679: argv[12] = -o
scp:Scp2/scp2.c:1679: argv[13] = authenticationnotify yes
scp:Scp2/scp2.c:1679: argv[14] = xxx.xxx.xxx.51
scp:Scp2/scp2.c:1679: argv[15] = -s
scp:Scp2/scp2.c:1679: argv[16] = sftp
debug: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.51, port 22... (SOCKS not used)
debug: Ssh2/ssh2.c:2121: Entering event loop.
debug: Ssh2Client/sshclient.c:1403: Creating transport protocol.
debug: SshAuthMethodClient/sshauthmethodc.c:83: Added "publickey" to usable methods.
debug: SshAuthMethodClient/sshauthmethodc.c:83: Added "password" to usable methods.
debug: Ssh2Client/sshclient.c:1444: Creating userauth protocol.
debug: client supports 2 auth methods: 'publickey,password'
debug: Ssh2Common/sshcommon.c:559: local ip = xxx.xxx.xxx.35, local port = 56985
debug: Ssh2Common/sshcommon.c:561: remote ip = xxx.xxx.xxx.51, remote port = 22
debug: SshConnection/sshconn.c:1930: Wrapping...
debug: Ssh2/ssh2.c:899: Opening /dev/tty for queries.
debug: Remote version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug: Ssh2Transport/trcommon.c:1306: Remote version has rekey incompatibility bug.
debug: Ssh2Transport/trcommon.c:1308: Remote version is OpenSSH, KEX guesses disabled.
debug: Ssh2Transport/trcommon.c:1647: lang s to c: `', lang c to s: `'
debug: Ssh2Transport/trcommon.c:1712: c_to_s: cipher aes128-cbc, mac hmac-sha1, compression none
debug: Ssh2Transport/trcommon.c:1715: s_to_c: cipher aes128-cbc, mac hmac-sha1, compression none
debug: Remote host key found from database.
debug: Ssh2Common/sshcommon.c:317: Received SSH_CROSS_STARTUP packet from connection protocol.
debug: Ssh2Common/sshcommon.c:367: Received SSH_CROSS_ALGORITHMS packet from connection protocol.
debug: server offers auth methods 'publickey,password,keyboard-interactive'.
debug: Ssh2AuthPubKeyClient/authc-pubkey.c:1535: adding keyfile "/devapp_users/nsdtest/.ssh2/nsdau187" to candidates
debug: Ssh2AuthPubKeyClient/authc-pubkey.c:1535: adding keyfile "/devapp_users/nsdtest/.ssh2/id_dsa_1024_a" to candidates
debug: Ssh2AuthPubKeyClient/authc-pubkey.c:1535: adding keyfile "/devapp_users/nsdtest/.ssh2/id_dsa_1024_b" to candidates
debug: Constructing and sending signature in publickey authentication.
debug: Ssh2AuthPubKeyClient/authc-pubkey.c:772: ssh_client_auth_pubkey_send_signature: reading /devapp_users/nsdtest/.ssh2/nsdau187
debug: Ssh2AuthPubKeyClient/authc-pubkey.c:1751: Public key authentication was successful.
debug: Ssh2Common/sshcommon.c:285: Received SSH_CROSS_AUTHENTICATED packet from connection protocol.
debug: Ssh2/ssh2.c:650: Returning user input stream to original values.
debug: Ssh2Common/sshcommon.c:829: num_channels now 1
scp:SshFCTransfer/sshfc_transfer.c:130: Source file is "raw", and it needs to be parsed.
debug: SshTtyFlags/sshttyflags.c:354: Not a tty. (fd = 0)
scp:SshFCTransfer/sshfc_transfer.c:1319: No connection yet. Waiting...
scp:SshFileXferClient/sshfilexferc.c:981: ssh_file_client_receive_proc: bad VERSION
scp:SshFCTransfer/sshfc_transfer.c:1319: No connection yet. Waiting...
scp:SshFCTransfer/sshfc_transfer.c:1319: No connection yet. Waiting...
scp:SshFCTransfer/sshfc_transfer.c:1319: No connection yet. Waiting...
scp:SshFCTransfer/sshfc_transfer.c:1319: No connection yet. Waiting...
scp:SshFCTransfer/sshfc_transfer.c:1319: No connection yet. Waiting...
[...] same until the user presses Ctrl+C

user@srv/home/user> debug: SshConnection/sshconn.c:405: EOF from channel stream
debug: Ssh2ChannelSession/sshchsession.c:1721: received exit status : 0
debug: Ssh2Common/sshcommon.c:803: num_channels now 0
debug: Got session close with exit_status=0
debug: destroying client struct...
debug: Ssh2Client/sshclient.c:1478: Destroying client.
debug: SshConfig/sshconfig.c:555: Freeing pki. (host_pki != NULL, user_pki = NULL)
debug: SshConnection/sshconn.c:1982: Destroying SshConn object.
debug: Ssh2Client/sshclient.c:1540: Destroying client completed.
debug: SshAuthMethodClient/sshauthmethodc.c:88: Destroying authentication method array.
debug: SshAppCommon/sshappcommon.c:146: Freeing global SshRegex context.
debug: SshConfig/sshconfig.c:555: Freeing pki. (host_pki = NULL, user_pki = NULL)
```

And here are the entries form the server log

```
Jun 3 07:22:36 localhost sshd[19898]: Accepted publickey for cdr from xxx.xxx.xx.x port 53119 ssh2
Jun 3 07:22:36 localhost sshd[19900]: subsystem request for sftp
Jun 3 07:22:58 localhost snmpd[8500]: netsnmp_assert index == tmp failed if-mib/data_access/interface.c:467 _access_interface_entry_save_name()
Jun 3 07:23:58 localhost last message repeated 4 times
```

Edit: "Subsystem sftp internal-sftp" is already enabled in the conf file, and I can sftp files form the server without problems.

Edit: Trying without the keys by specifying a username/password does not work either.
Reverting back to the older version works, so that's what we are doing for now.

Btw we suspected this line

```
debug: SshTtyFlags/sshttyflags.c:354: Not a tty. (fd = 0)
```

might mean the shell is sending something which is showing on the ssh console but messing up the scp, but nothing seems to be sent on ssh (and .bashrc seems clean) and I cannot view the decrypted scp traffic to see if something is being sent wrongly.

Comment: The logs show the problem. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

What does "unable to scp files" any more mean? What is the error message they get?

Check your logs (/var/log/syslog, /var/log/messages, /var/log/daemon.log) to see if the SSH server is throwing any errors. They should be pretty descriptive.  With the logs and the customer's error, we should be able to narrow down what the problem is.

**Edit**

The logs you posted indicate the most likely problem:

> scp:Scp2/scp2.c:1679: argv[16] = sftp
>   ...
>   scp:SshFileXferClient/sshfilexferc.c:981: ssh_file_client_receive_proc: bad VERSION

Looks like this thing is trying to use the sftp protocol rather than scp directly. OpenSSH, by default, disables the sftp subsystem. I don't know when this change was made, but it sounds likely. Add this to your sshd_config and see if it changes things:

> Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp

Comment: I added the logs from scp -v is that enough as logs form the client side ?

Comment: That should be fine from the client. Can you post logs from the server side, as well as your sshd_config?

Comment: Doesn't seem like sftp issue! I edited the question with more info / logs.

Comment: I'm striking out on this one. Can you add LogLevel Debug2 to your sshd_config and post the relevant logs? Glance through the debug logs and mung any sensitive data before posting it.

Comment: Ok I'll do that, but it'll have to wait till monday.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of potential issues.  First, have you examined the logs on your server to see if there are any clues?  Is it possible that the upgrade changed a setting that either the client cannot use or is not set to use.  For example, does your server now require SSH2 but the client is using only SSH1?

Log files will likely provide the way to the answer.  If the SCP client can do any logging, that could be helpful as well.

Comment: I added the logs from scp -v is that enough?

Answer (score 0):

This my have something to do with the openssh key vulnerability that was fixed. All vulnerable keys got black-listed and should be re-created. Just check to see if they can delete the cached fingerprints of your sever. Ons this is done, the client should show the new fingerprint to the user and ask them if they accept it.
They reason the SSH may work, is that the app could have asked the user if they accept the new key, or initial contact was made after the upgrade.

Comment: But if they accept the keys for ssh shouldnl't the same key be used (and accepted) for scp ?

Comment: Not if the two apps store their cached fingerprints in different locations.

Comment: We tried without the cached keys (by entering a username / password) and still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

As stated previously, there are lots of possibilities.  I'd start with this line though:

```
scp:SshFileXferClient/sshfilexferc.c:981: ssh_file_client_receive_proc: bad VERSION
scp:SshFCTransfer/sshfc_transfer.c:1319: No connection yet. Waiting...
```

At first glance it looks like the client doens't like what it sees and drops the connection in an unclean manner.

Have you tried putting back the previous version of sshd and seeing what happens?
What happens when the client attempts to ssh in without using keys?

Comment: Connecting without the keys (username / password) does not work either. Reverting back to the old version makes everything work again, which is what we are doing until we figure something else.

Comment: What does running strace on sshd show when the client tries to connect?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced same issue while using SSH client dibug log showing...
FileTransferWin/filetransferwin.c:217: Received error SSH_FC_OK, error message No files to transfer.

After hours of long experiments I undestand that SSH don't like to trasfer file form folders such with special character used in it's name i.e 'Files to (Transfer)' After changing folder name to 'Files_to_Transfer' it worked fine.